# Wordpress : Handle CSS priority between Child & Parent Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I started working on a wordpress website. After choosing a theme, I decided to customize it using the child theme way.

I followed the common method using this :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'parent-style' ) );
}
```

Using it, It wasn't working well because my parent already has a enqueue function with a lot of CSS stylesheet and where the order is important, particularly about the bootstrap CSS which has to be overrided by the parent stylesheet.

From here, 2 solutions :

- Copy and paste the whole enqueue parent function (so we replace the parent function by the child one. To me, the Pro is we keep the original order of the queue, the Con is we totally skip the original function which could be updated.
- Use this code as child enqueue function :

  ```
     function theme_enqueue_styles() {
     wp_deregister_style('zerif_bootstrap_style');
     wp_enqueue_style('zerif_bootstrap_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');
     wp_enqueue_style( 'zerif-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'    );
     wp_enqueue_style( 'cleverdrive-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'zerif-style' ) );
     }
  ```

In my case, It looks work well, but if the original order of the *deregistered* style is important, I think we do not keep it.

According to you, what is the best way to handle this case ?

Thanks you,

Sommy

Comment: Can you try enqueing the extra js and css files in your child theme using a different function but `wp_enqueue_scripts` with a later priority or `wp_footer` hook . that will keep your parent theme function working and child theme function is also going work.

Comment: Hi, It works ! Easy and efficient, perfect ! Thanks you

Comment: than mark my comment as useful and your question is resolved .

Comment: I have already added the answer please mark it as solution, so that it will be helpful to someone else.

Comment: First time I use Stackoverflow, I searched how to turn this topic solve, now I know :-) Thx

Comment: I am also learning about this platform :) This is 4th day I will be answering and I am now in top 2% of this month , thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enqueing the extra js `enter code here`and `css` files in your child theme using a different function but `wp_enqueue_scripts` with a later priority or `wp_footer` hook . that will keep your parent theme function working and child theme function is also going work.